# Vaadin 14 - non-modal dialog resizing

Tags: java, css, dialog, modal-dialog, vaadin

I created a resizable and non-modal dialog in Vaadin 14 according to suggestions and it works basically. It appears at the center of the screen. I would like to change the content of it and dynamically resizing of it according to actual content. While I not moving the dialog from the starting position everything is working fine but after relocating it to another position I can not change the height and width of it. Something fixes these properties but unfortunately I did not found the reason of it within CSS. Do you know a solution for that?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Source is really simple only the content is changing by a button. Main component is a Dialog as it was suggested in Vaadin example. No failures and no exceptions during running.

Comment: I could attach some picture about appearence of dialog and the issue but unfortunately there is no possibility to attach image file to this comment.

Comment: I found the reason why it is happening. When I relocate the dialog the id='overlay' DIV width and height property will be updated. These two settings are fixing the size of dialog. If I delete these two style parameters then the dialog will fit again the content of it. The issue is that the workaround solution (after changing content I reset the height and width from Javascript) is not working. Any comment?

Comment: document.getElementById('overlay').style.width  = 'auto';
document.getElementById('overlay').style.height = 'auto';